# When will Google Cloud Serverless VPC be available in Europe?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Currently serverless VPC is available only for us-central. When will we get it in Europe, as its a blocker due to regulations. We really want to use Google Cloud Functions with memorystore!

Comment: Hi @Tom Larkworthy! Can you accept Alex Riquelme solution? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serverless VPC Access currently supports the following regions via API and CLI:

- us-central1
- us-east1
- europe-west1

You can try it with the following command:

```
gcloud beta compute networks vpc-access connectors create [CONNECTOR_NAME] \
--network [VPC_NETWORK] \
--region europe-west1 \
--range [IP_RANGE]
```